# DOM element objects and style

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
</head>
<body>
<script>
    var htmlElement = document.documentElement;
    var headElement = htmlElement.firstChild;
    /*Create title and title content*/
    var titleTag = document.createElement("title");
    var titleText = document.createTextNode("my page");
    titleTag.appendChild(titleText);
    headElement.appendChild(titleTag);
    
    var bodyElement = headElement.nextSibling.nextSibling;
    /*create paragraph and content*/
    
    var count = 0;
    while (count < 5){
        var paraTag = document.createElement("p");
        var paraText = document.createTextNode("This is text");
        paraTag.appendChild(paraText);
        bodyElement.appendChild(paraTag);
        count++;
    }
    paraTag.id = "para";
    document.getElementById("para").style.color = "yellow"
    paraTag.previousSibling.style.color = "red";
    paraTag.previousSibling.previousSibling.style.color = "blue";
    paraTag.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.style.color = "green";
    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi everybody. I am new to JS and playing with DOM elements.

My questions:

1. When I tried to style tag by ID it makes only last element yellow. Why?
2. When I tried to style tag by reference to nextSibling tag it gives me null. Why?
3. When I looped to create paragraphs it built backwards, so I need to use previousSibling to get to element?

Comment: Yellow color is caused by `document.getElementById("para").style.color = "yellow"` and since paraTag holds the last `<p>` item, the last one will be yellow

Comment: When I assigned ID to paraTag.previousSibling.id = "para"; it removes any style for 4th element. If I put paraTag.id = "para"; in the loop I thought it would create id for all < p > but it's not.

Comment: 1.In DOM ID is unique that's why When you search with ID it will return first matched element. 2. As 'para' id set to last element there is no next sibling so it returns null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Id should be unique for every tag .So in this scenario only the last element is getting the id as `para` .Also the `paraTag` contains the last `<p>` element that is why it is only changing the value of the last element.

And you have to use the `previousSibling` because as i mention your `paraTag` contains the last element of `<p>` tag so all the tag have been created before that .That's why you have to use `previousSibling` to access the rest of the tags

Answer (score 1):

All of your question is linked to 1 fact, that you are assigning the id to the last item in the loop, once you exist the loop `paraTag` holds the last `<p>` generated.

`paraTag.id = "para";`

- When I tried to style tag by ID it makes only last element yellow. Why?
  Yellow color is caused by `document.getElementById("para").style.color = "yellow"` and since paraTag holds the last

  item, the last one will be yellow
- When I tried to style tag by reference to nextSibling tag it gives me null. Why?
  `paraTag` holds the last item, there is no next.
- When I looped to create paragraphs it built backwards, so I need to use previousSibling to get to element?
  since `paraTag` is the last you have to use `previousSibling`

I think its better to assign every item an id inside the loop based on `count` and then do whatever you want using the right id as below:

```
 var count = 0;
    while (count < 5){
        var paraTag = document.createElement("p");
        var paraText = document.createTextNode("This is text");
        paraTag.appendChild(paraText);
        bodyElement.appendChild(paraTag);
        paraTag.id = "para_" + count;
    //you can get the item by document.getElementById("para0")
        count++;
    }
```

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. One other thing that might be useful to you Misha is that the id attribute is meant to be used in conjunction with a unique element. I'm not sure if you understand this, as your question is in part about your confusion that you were only able to select and change the color of the last element. I don't think that getElementByID will get more than one element, that's what getElementsByClassName is for.

Comment: Thanks. I understood the concept. Now all of this make sense